# Unable to enable / disable Mosaic using NVAPI

Tags: c++, visual-c++, nvidia, nvapi

I'm working on some code to enable and disable Mosaic via NVAPI on a Quadro P4000.

I've set Mosaic to be active via the Nvidia utilities on the machine and it works. However, when I try to disable the Mosaic settings via code I receive the NVAPI_NO_IMPLEMENTATION status error.

This is the code I'm using:

```
void disableMosaic()
{
    NvAPI_Status error;
    NvAPI_ShortString estring;


    NvAPI_Initialize();

    error = NvAPI_EnableCurrentMosaicTopology(0);

    if (error != NVAPI_OK)
    {
        NvAPI_GetErrorMessage(error, estring);
        printf("Error disabling Mosaic: %s\n", estring);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Mosaic disabled successfully.\n");
    }
}
```

According to the [documentation from Nvidia](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/coresdk/nvapi/group__nvapistatus.html#gga12534f3b520256799842c0172e9afdf7a41bb28148f4d6322272db3bb97e9ab7a), this means that the drivers don't support this feature, though I find this a bit vague, the drivers are well established and it's not a new card. Does anyone know if this might be something else or am I wasting my time with this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more investigation, it turns out the error message is right, but there is a work around.

The `NvAPI_EnableCurrentMosaicTopology()` method is for Windows XP (most of the example code I've found in this area has been quite old, hence this mistake). To get this functionality working on Windows 7 - 10 there is a different method to use: `NvAPI_Mosaic_EnableCurrentTopo()`.